# What does in:"query" mean when describing parameters in swagger for apigee127?

Tags: yaml, swagger, apigee127

I am new to making APIs, and I have recently installed apigee 127 to make APIs using swagger. But there are a few things I do not understand. I was going through an example which is as follows(relevant to question):

```
parameters:
    -
      name: "name"
      in: "query"
      description: "The name of the person to whom to say hello"
      required: false
      type: "string"
```

What does

```
in: "query"
```

mean in the above YAML data? Kindly suggest which documentations are to be read to understand the above better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`in : "query"` specifies that the parameter 'name' is a query parameter. In other words, the given API will accept a name query parameter.

For more details, you can refer the YAML specification -

http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html

AND / OR

http://swagger.io/specification/#parameterObject 
http://swagger.io/specification/#parameterIn